# $\Omega^2(S) \cong \tau(S)$ for simple modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be an Artin algebra with $\Omega^2(S) \cong \tau(S)$ for each simple module $S$. Is $A$ a quasi-Frobenius (=selfinjective) algebra?
Here $\tau$ denotes the Auslander-Reiten translate, which is defined for example in section 3.3. proposition 3.3.1. in https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/angeleri.pdf.
$\Omega^n(M)$ denotes the $n$-th syzygy of a module $M$.

Note that $\Omega^2(S) \cong \tau(S)$ is always true over symmetric algebras, which motivated this question.
More general, for quasi-Frobenius algebras one always has $\nu \Omega^2(S) \cong \tau(S)$ with the Nakayama functor $\nu$,so one might ask the same question with $\nu \Omega^2(S) \cong \tau(S)$ instead of $\Omega^2(S) \cong \tau(S)$.

Both questions should have a positive answer for Nakayama algebras.

Comment: Would you explain the terminology?

Comment: Sorry, but what is $\Omega^2(S)$?

Comment: @YCor just the second syzygy module. I thought this is a quite common notation.

Comment: No problem it's common, but I don't know all common notation of all fields... and $\Omega^2$ evoked me a module of differentials.

Comment: @YCor Thanks for the remark, the question is now probably more understandable for more people.